# Help Regarding the result of this regular expression

Tags: regex

```
 var pat = /(^[\w\.\+\-=]+@[\w\.\-]+\.[\w\-]+$)/g
```

I want to use this as a email validator.. I found it in a forum.

But I am not aware of ^ /g and forward slash and the structure /(  * )/g ?

.+-= what does this represent ??

Comment: Well, if you want to use it then go ahead. But you should really do a search for `email validation <your-language>` here on SO in order to see whether better alternatives exist.

Comment: ^ represents the start of a new line and \g is a global search ... aka all.

Comment: no this is already in the code I am working on .. I should chk whether it's working or not.. thats it..

Comment: @Adam what is global search? why do I need that?

Comment: Hi Praneel, global is like a 'match all', instead of stopping at the first occurrence, it continues to find all matches that conform to the expression

Comment: Hi Pranell, you are welcome, just in case you didn't notice, email@domain.c matches your expression, a minor edit to the expression would fix this ... (^[\w\.\+\-=]+@[\w\.\-]+\.[\w\-]{2,5}$)  ... {2,5} instead of + .. + is one or more, where {2,5} says the extension must be 2-5 characters long which would handle things like .ca, .net or .info (up to 5 charaters)

Comment: thnx @Adam I would like to know how can u test this regex?

Comment: Hi Pranell, I apologize for the delay in response to you.  I use Antix Regex Tester found at http://antix.co.uk/Projects/Regex-Tester , it is free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pattern

```
/(^[\w\.\+\-=]+@[\w\.\-]+\.[\w\-]+$)/g
```

contains those elements:

`/ ... /` Regex pattern delimiter

`/ ... /g` Regex pattern modifier here `g` global pattern ==> match all occurrences

`^` Anchor for the start of the string, forces the pattern to match from the start of the string on.

`$` Anchor for the end of the string

`[]` Square brackets define a character class, i.e. this construct matches one character of those included in this class. `[\w\.\+\-=]` matches either a word character or a `.` `+` `-` `=`
Inside such a character class you don't need to escape most of the characters. So `[\w.+\-=]` would have the same meaning (and `[\w.+=-]` also)

`\w` is a word character, depends on your regex engine, but at least a-zA-Z0-9 and _

`+` means matches the previous part at least once, `[\w\.\+\-=]+` matches for example "Foobar", "++++=", ".", ".Foo=098+-"

There exist several online test tools for regexes. [See your regex for example here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2ubrt)

Answer (score 1):

`^` is the anchor for the start of string.

The `/` are the regex delimiters.

The `g` is the *global pattern modifier*.

Answer (score 1):

The "g" stands for "global", which tells Perl to replace all matches, and not just the first one. Options are typically indicated including the slash, like "/g", even though you do not add an extra slash, and even though you could use any non-word character instead of slashes.

Example:

```
s/cat/dog/g
```

< The zoo had wild dogs, bobcats, lions, and other wild cats.

All cat will be replaced by dog

> The zoo had wild dogs, bobdogs, lions, and other wild dogs.

Comment: in this context /*/g         empty string is replaced by the formatted string ??